# passing listbox and combox as one argument

Tags: c#, combobox, listbox, parameter-passing

I remove things from a listbox or a combobox. I have two functions for this which are the same....

```
    public static void removeFromListBox(ListBox ListToRmvthings)//remove items from a Listbox general purpose
    {
        int NumberOfIdx = ListToRmvthings.Items.Count;
        if (NumberOfIdx > 0)
        {
            for (int inc = NumberOfIdx - 1; inc >= 0; --inc)
            {
                ListToRmvthings.Items.RemoveAt(inc);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void removeFromComboBox(ComboBox ComboToRmvthings)//remove items from a Combobox general purpose
    {
        int NumberOfIdx = ComboToRmvthings.Items.Count;
        if (NumberOfIdx > 0)
        {
            for (int inc = NumberOfIdx - 1; inc >= 0; --inc)
            {
                ComboToRmvthings.Items.RemoveAt(inc);
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I make only one function... cause if I try to pass object it doesn^t recognize the items.count....

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both derive from `ListControl`. But as someone pointed out, the `Items` property is not in that base class -- both controls have their own `Items` property and their own types for representing them.

So it seems there is no better way than to provide two methods. The methods are simple, so trying to fit in two types by means of type testing and coercion would only serve to complicate matters.

Comment: The [ListControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx)'s documentation doesn't seem to have a `Items` property.